# RecylerView Button does not trigger

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a button in my  recycler card which is needed to show a `popupMenu`

However, whenever user clicks on this button, `popupMenu` does not appear. Even I put a break point inside the `menuOptionsButton.Click` action, it does not hit.

**ImageButton in XML**

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/MoreSettings"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_more_black_24dp" />
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.cs**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter : MvxRecyclerAdapter
{
  private readonly FragmentActivity _activity;

  public RecyclerAdapter(IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext, FragmentActivity activity)
        : base(bindingContext)
  {
    _activity = activity;
  }

  public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
  {
    base.OnBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    var view = holder.ItemView;
    var menuOptionsButton = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.MoreSettings);
    menuOptionsButton.Click += (s, e) =>
     {
         var popup = new PopupMenu(_activity, menuOptionsButton );
         popup.MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu,popup.Menu);
         popup.Show();
     };
  }
}
```

If I do not put `popupMenu` inside the click action, then each item in the recyclerview shows a `popupMenu`, but I want to have an action click to show `popUpMenu`.

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    base.OnBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    var view = holder.ItemView;
    var menuOptionsButton = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.MoreSettings);
    var popup = new PopupMenu(_activity, menuOptionsButton );
    popup.MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu,popup.Menu);
    popup.Show();
}
```

UPDATE :

**Activity.cs**

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.AView, null);   
    HasOptionsMenu = true;
    toolbar = ((MainView)Activity).SupportActionBar;   
    var recyclerView = view.FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.ARecyclerView);
    if (recyclerView != null)
    {
        recyclerView.HasFixedSize = true;
        recyclerView.Adapter = new RecyclerAdapter((IMvxAndroidBindingContext)BindingContext, Activity);
        var layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Activity);
        recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
      }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: The id is different `MoreOptions` vs `MoreSettings`

Comment: Sorry, it was typo, I have fixed and also add additional information to my question.

Comment: Are you perhaps building with linker set to `Sdk Assemblies Only` or  `Sdk and user Assemblies`?

Comment: Linker properties is `none`

Comment: @hotspring Do you have a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` subclass? Can you add your `RecyclerAdapter.OnCreateViewHolder` override....

Comment: No I dont have `RecylerView.ViewHolder` subclass. I have also added `Activity.cs` class in my question.

Comment: Based on this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521089/animate-selected-item-in-mvxrecyclerview, I do not see `ViewHolder` subclass.

Comment: Why not using a bindable ListView like the MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView and a binding on your button?

Comment: Could you please illustrate your idea? giving a small example. My button is a menu button, which needs to open a `popupMenu`

Answer (score 0):

In your RecyclerView.Adapter code, you should be careful when adding a Click delegate inside the OnBindViewHolder method. If you add as a C# anonymous function, then every time that the View shows a new delegate will be added, not set.

First, you should place this line inside the ViewHolder constructor method:

```
this.menuOptionsButton = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.MoreSettings);
```

Then,

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    base.OnBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    var optionsButton = ((YourHolder)holder).menuOptionsButton;

    // This avoids adding a Click event more than once
    optionsButton.Click -= this.PopupShow;
    optionsButton.Click += this.PopupShow;
}

private void PopupShow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Toast.MakeText(this.context, "Button clicked", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    var popup = new PopupMenu(_activity, menuOptionsButton );
    popup.MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu,popup.Menu);
    popup.Show();
}
```